# Transferring downloaded games from mac to mac

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

I am downloading a Game in Steam in iMac which is present in my friends place. I want to take the downloaded game to my mac.  my internet is too slow so i am downloading it in my friends mac. i am downloading Team fortress 2 can anyone tell me how to download and take the game to my mac

Comment: Isn't there a backup function like on the PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Account menu, you have the “Backup and Restore Games…” option; use this to copy TF2 to a thumb drive or equivalent, and at home, restore TF2 to your computer from the drive using the same feature.